# How to find if an element exists within a character array in java

Tags: java, arrays

Here is the thing. I have a character array as follows..

```
char[] modes = new char[] { 'm', 'q', 'h', 'y' };
```

Now I want to provide the user with the option to enter a character. If it exists in the `modes` array, I'll do the necessary. For that I used...

```
//to take a character as input
mode = input.next().charAt(0);
//now to check if the array contains the character
boolean ifExists = Arrays.asList(modes).contains(mode);
```

But strangely `ifExists` returns `false`.

1. Any Ideas where am I doing wrong?
2. If this is a bad way of doing it, please suggest a way.

Comment: "Strangely" on what input? I wouldn't find it strange if the input was `a`.

Comment: I suggest that you, on the code line before `ifExists` is evaluated print the value of `mode` and the value of all contents in the `modes` array. Probably, some value is not what you expect...

Comment: Why arent you using the `binarySearch` method on `Arrays`?

Comment: @Alex -  my input was **m**

Comment: @Perception - i can always use binary search..but i am more eager to know if there is something in built. or something like that.

Comment: @pjp - `binarySearch` is a method on the same `Arrays` class you are using. See the answer from @PatBurke for an example on how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's Autoboxing - the contains() method takes an object, not a primitive.

If you use Character instead of char it will work:

```
    Character[] modes = new Character[] { 'm', 'q', 'h', 'y' };

    //to take a character as input
    Character mode = "q123".charAt(0);
    //now to check if the array contains the character
    boolean ifExists = Arrays.asList(modes).contains(mode);
```

returns true

Comment: Won't autoboxing automatically kick in in this case? I'm curious as to why Java did not automatically wrap the primitives as objects.

Comment: It does kick in. Looking at the source code of contains(), it uses equals() under the hood, at that does work on autoboxed chars. I'm confused -Edit - Pat Burke has the answer

Comment: @Redandwhite - thanks for asking that. I too was curious about that.

Comment: Autoboxing doesn't kick in because Java doesn't autobox arrays.  The parameter to `Arrays.asList` is `T...`, and `T` needs to be an Object type.  For instance, `Object[] array = new char[0];` will not compile.

Answer (score 3):

The Arrays.asList() method is returning a List of char[] and not a List of char like you are expecting. I would recommend using the Arrays.binarySort() method like so:

```
    char[] modes = new char[] { 'm', 'q', 'h', 'y' };

    char mode = 'q';

    //now to check if the array contains the character
    int index = Arrays.binarySearch(modes, mode);
    boolean ifExists = index != -1;
    System.out.print(ifExists);
```

Comment: For the situation given, it works in all cases. Could you provide a case where it wold not work?

Comment: Actually, `Arrays.binarySearch(modes, 'h')` results in `-1`, where a negative value indicates the key is not in the array.

Comment: Interesting, must have overlooked that one! Good call.

Comment: Could just use `Arrays.sort(modes)` before searching it I suppose, but I don't know whether the order in `modes` is important in OP's program or not.  (Seems like no, or he'd have been using `indexOf` instead of `contains`.)  By the way, the docs for `binarySearch` also say it can return other negative values besides `-1`, so probably should use `ifExists = index >= 0` or something to be a little more robust.  Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any problem with your code and try this,

**If you use this kind of Colletions then you can do lots of operations using methods available defaultly...**

```
List<Character> l = new ArrayList<Character>();
l.add('a');
l.add('b');
l.add('c');
System.out.println(l.contains('a'));
```

Comment: I know i can use a lot of things while working with collections..but i want to know how to do it when it is a primitive array.

Answer (score 1):

You could just convert to a string and then run [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

```
new String(modes).contains("" + mode);
```

This should then return true or false for your primitive array

Comment: why concatenate that empty string? please explain.

Comment: Concatenating `mode` with an empty string just converts it to a string.  Could also use `String.valueOf(mode)` for essentially the same result.

Comment: Thanks matts. yes I could use String.valueOf instead. I am converting more from chat to String

Answer (score 0):

You could also use String indexOf:

```
boolean ifExists = new String(modes).indexOf(mode) >= 0;
```

or

```
boolean ifExists = "mqhy".indexOf(mode) >= 0;
```